# Possible to constant propagate if statement without dispatch?

Tags: optimization, julia

Julia (v0.5) does not constant propagate the following, leading to poor performance:

```
julia> g(::Int) = true
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(x) = g(x) ? 1 : 1.0
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype f(1)
Variables:
  #self#::#f
  x::Int64

Body:
  begin 
      unless $(QuoteNode(true)) goto 3
      return 1
      3: 
      return 1.0
  end::Union{Float64,Int64}
```

Instead, I have to do the following:

```
julia> g(::Int) = Val{true}
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f_(::Type{Val{true}}) = 1
f_ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f_(::Type{Val{false}}) = 1.0
f_ (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f(x) = f_(g(x))
f (generic function with 1 method)
```

Although this works, it requires defining an additional function, which creates additional compile-time overhead. Is there an existing solution that works on v0.5, without this overhead?

Comment: This seems like more of a performance issue to be filed than a stack overflow question.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski My understanding is that the compiler already does constant propagation, inlining, and inference, but these steps can be iterated and combined _ad nauseum_, and so there is no way to ensure the best performance in all cases without making compilation time unreasonable. So I am interested in whether a way exists that works with the existing behaviour.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski Nevertheless, I submitted issue https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17880.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note in the issue you posted, LLVM does indeed do this constant propagation so there's no branch at runtime. The issue is simply that the method is still type-unstable since inference isn't the one doing the constant propagation and dead code elimination.

Another possible workaround for this sort of type-inference issue is a generated function.  It's very heavy-handed, though, and is likely to have even more compile-time overhead.

Indeed, if you look at the first-run times, you can see that while the generated function needs fewer allocations, it still takes about 2-3x longer. Both lower to the exact same LLVM/native code, so the only consideration here is compile-time and complexity.  And in that regard, the generated function loses handily. I think your current workaround is as good as it gets for now.

```
julia> g(::Int) = Val{true}
       f_(::Type{Val{true}}) = 1
       f_(::Type{Val{false}}) = 1.0
       f(x) = f_(g(x))
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time f(1)
  0.002720 seconds (521 allocations: 30.203 KB)

julia> g′(::Type{Int}) = true
       @generated f′(x) = g′(x) ? 1 : 1.0
f′ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time f′(1)
  0.007655 seconds (351 allocations: 21.125 KB)
```